# MySQL grouping error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a query on a table to see how many unique users have a usage record in the system at a given point.  I've been working with the following query, but I've yet to see a proper result.

```
SELECT count(distinct usageUser), divisionName
FROM records R 
INNER JOIN locate L  
    ON L.computerID=R.usageComputerID
WHERE R.usageWhen LIKE "2012-07-08T12:%"
GROUP BY L.divisionName;
```

Currently the query returns 18, for each division in the joined table.  Without the GROUP BY clause I get the same number of records.

EDIT:
I ran the query again, with suggestions from a comment.  By removing the group by and count clause, I get this [this](http://pastebin.com/Wh8y1EuY) (too big to post).  This data is very poorly formatted, unfortunately it's inherited and fairly large.

It is not possible for these users to have used every lab like it's listed.

Comment: Why do you think that this is wrong? Are there 18 different divisonName values or not?

Comment: Your query looks correct to me. Run it without GROUP BY and COUNT and check if the results make sense.

Comment: @idious It's telling me there are 18 distinct users in *each* division which is incorrect.  There are 49 divisions total.

Vatev: I will post an edit in just a moment.

Comment: I don't see anything blatantly wrong here, though if `usageWhen` is a datetime or timestamp type *and* has an index you can optimize the query by changing the `WHERE` clause: `WHERE R.usageWhen >= '2012-07-08 12:00:00' AND R.usageWhen < '2012-07-08 13:00:00'`.

Comment: @Ed Gibbs: I really wish... Unfortunately, the data is fairly large and is inherited;  it's stored as a varchar.

Comment: Well, the GROUP BY results match the raw data all right. But if, as you say, it should not be that every user gets associated with all the division names, then the most likely issue is your join condition, which probably doesn't reflect the relationship between the two tables properly. In other words, joining on `ComputerID` alone must be not enough, but what *is* enough, is impossible to tell without at least seeing the structures of those tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) cnt, L.divisionName, R.usageUser 
FROM records R 
INNER JOIN locate L  
    ON L.computerID=R.usageComputerID
WHERE R.usageWhen LIKE "2012-07-08T12:%"
GROUP BY L.divisionName,R.usageUser;
```